# how to randomly select an element from an array having the least probability

Tags: matlab, random, probability

how to randomly select an element from an array having the least probability in matlab

example :

```
      A = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6]

      P = [ 0.01,0.2,0.25.0.2,0.25,0.09] % probability %
```

Comment: How will it random and still have the least probability? You mean only one of multiple elements if multiple elements have equally less probability?

Comment: yes ...... ii want to select an element with least probablility

Comment: So in above example, you would select the 6 because it has least probability, but where is the randomness?

Comment: @Daniel As I understand it, the minimum is 0.01 and hence 1. but if two elements had 0.01 then any one of those elements could be chosen randomly. @ PAnilKumar Please confirm

Comment: yes .... @Daniel

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean. It makes no sense to randomly select something specific. You either randomly select any element, or  you select a specific element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find [all indices of the minimum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mink.html) probabilities. Then generate a [random interger](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) depending on the [number](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) of equally minimum probabilities. Then use [matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html) to extract a random index of minimum probability and then its corresponding element.

```
[~, ind] = mink(P,2); %All indices of minimum elements
Result = A(inds(randi(numel(inds))));   %Random minimum element
```